# How to apply CSS to a particular asp.net table?

Tags: css, asp.net, css-tables

I have downloaded a .css style sheet from a website that include many styling for table. I want to apply that .css style sheet to a particular asp.net table. So in aspx I have,

```
          <asp:Table cssClass="downloadedCss">
          </asp:Table>
```

In the css stylesheet I downloaded it has many things such as ..

```
           table {}
           caption{}
           td, th  {}
           tr {}
           thead th, tfoot th {}
           tbody td a  {}
           tbody td a:visited  {}
           tbody td a:hover {}
           tbody th a  {}
           tbody th a:hover {}
           tbody td+td+td+td a {}
           tbody td+td+td+td a:visited  {}
           tbody th, tbody td {}
           tfoot td {}
           tbody tr:hover  {}
```

How to make all those css properties to apply for just the table (downloadedCss class)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An ASP.NET Table will render as a HTML Table.

Your example will render like:

```
<table class="downloadedCss">
</table>
```

Therefore your current CSS rules will all apply to this table. If you want these styles to **only** apply to this table, then specify the class name in the CSS rules.

```
       table.downloadedCss {}
       table.downloadedCss caption{}
       table.downloadedCss td, table.downloadedCss th  {}
       table.downloadedCss tr {}
       table.downloadedCss thead th, table.downloadedCss tfoot th {}
       table.downloadedCss tbody td a  {}
       table.downloadedCss tbody td a:visited  {}
       table.downloadedCss tbody td a:hover {}
       table.downloadedCss tbody th a  {}
       table.downloadedCss tbody th a:hover {}
       table.downloadedCss tbody td+td+td+td a {}
       table.downloadedCss tbody td+td+td+td a:visited  {}
       table.downloadedCss tbody th, table.downloadedCss tbody td {}
       table.downloadedCss tfoot td {}
       table.downloadedCss tbody tr:hover  {}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you change

```
table {}
```

to

```
table.downloadedCss {}
```

Then add that before all the other styles, then that will only apply those to that table. e.g.

```
table.downloadedCss caption {}
table.downloadedCss td, th {}
```

However I would probably strip out a lot of that css as I doubt you would need all of that.

Answer (score 1):

```
<table CssClass="pnlstudentDetails">
        <tr>
            <td>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

To apply Css for all the td elements under the specific table or panel or div try this code .
 .pnlstudentDetails td
        {
            height: 40px;
            vertical-align: middle;
            text-align: left;
            margin-top: 10px;
        }
```